# Unity Random.Range returns multiple integers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a Unity 3D game where I want to select one out of all the tagged player GameObjects at runtime.

I have a `Random.cs` script attached to the appropriate GameObjects / prefabs. I've created an array: `GameObject[] players` which takes in all the GameObjects with the tag: `Player`. I'm then using `Random.Range` to "randomly" select one of the array items every time the game starts.

The player GameObjects are at runtime generated by a random amount in another script. But these GameObjects do have this `Random.cs` script attached to them, so maybe they are just duplicating each other?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Random : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {
        GameObject[] players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
        int random = Random.Range(0, players.Length);
        Debug.Log("The random player is #: " + random);
    }
}
```

But what's happening now is that more than one of the array: `players` array items gets selected. A random `Debug.Log` looks like this: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are multiple gameObjects in the scene with the Random script attached. Start() in Random will be called once for each gameObject with the Random script attached. Each game object in the scene will create an instance of Random

One idea could be to instead have a single gameObject called GameManager or something, to which you attach this Random script.

Comment: Yeah I just figured it out, but thanks for the info. I now have a single GameObject which has the Random.cs script on it.